# To make Irssi System-beep

Tags: ubuntu, irssi

**How can you make Irssi system-beep without PC speakers?**

I know [this post](http://pookey.co.uk/blog/archives/2-Irssi-making-it-beep-when-your-nick-is-mentioned.html).
I have now also my PC speakers connected to my computer in the case that the sound starts to work with them.
However, this should not be necessary, since I should get the same sound as with `beep` witout these PC speakers.

My Irssi does not beep when my name is mentioned, although I put the following codes to my Irssi in Ubuntu

```
/set bell_beeps ON /set beep_msg_level MSGS NOTICES DCC DCCMSGS HILIGHT
```

and

```
/set bell_beeps = ON
```

I use Audible Beep also tried to set by `CTRL-A CTRL-G`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I answered a related query [here](https://superuser.com/questions/22767/enable-system-beep-in-ubuntu/22777#22777). On a similar vein, can you try the following:

- Check if pcspkr module is currently loaded

  > $ lsmod | grep pcspkr 
  >   pcspkr          10496  0
- If it is not, check if it has been blacklisted:

  > $ sudo grep pcspkr /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist* 
  >   /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist:blacklist pcspkr

  If you find such an entry, remove it and reboot.
- If it hasn't been blacklisted, check if the system speaker was identified properly at boot and if there are any related errors in */var/log/dmesg*

  > $ sudo grep pcspkr /var/log/dmesg  
  >   [   15.620198] input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input8
- If it there are no errors in */var/log/dmesg*, grep all other logs in /var/log/* with today's timestamp.

I'd also check Irssi to ensure it's not been configured to mute sounds.

Answer (score 0):

Is system beep disabled on your system?  From a terminal, type `beep` and see if you get a beep from your PC speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Fancy Beeper Daemon](http://www.carcosa.net/jason/software/beep/). I found a [blog post](http://autopragmatic.com/2009/01/19/redirect-linux-console-beep-to-the-sound-card/) that talks about setting it up, specifically with irssi and screen.