# Enable system beep in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I have tried to get the system beep working, but with no success. I used `echo -e '\a'` and the `beep` application.

I have tried entering `modprobe pcspkr` at the command line, and made sure pcspkr is not listed on the modprobe blacklist. I also enabled

- from the Gnome Desktop: System → Sound → System Beep → Enable audible beep,
- from a Terminal window: Edit → General → Terminal bell.

This did not fix the issue, though.

My computer is an IBM Thinkpad, iSeries laptop. I know my hardware speaker works, because if on startup the battery is low, it will beep.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/karmic/+source/linux/+bug/77010

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/19906/367990

Answer (score 15):

This might be a possible solution

What happens sometimes is the `pcspkr` might be added to blacklist, to remove it from the blacklist

Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist` and remove these lines if they exist :
(NOTE: You need to edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` instead)

```
# get rid of system beep

blacklist pcspkr
```

Reboot to deactivate this line.To disable the speaker (that emits the beep), add these lines and reboot.

This might solve your problem. Can provide more information if we know the system details.

If that doesn't solve your problem try running `sudo modprobe pcspkr` .

Comment: I did check the blacklist, but it wasn't listed.

Comment: Why rebooting? Just load the module manually.

Comment: This is the default for 10.04

Comment: Sadly, did not help.

Comment: how to load module manually?

Comment: Running `modprobe pcspkr` worked for enabling those horrible beeps on my Ubuntu Raring system.

Comment: @Robru Thanks that worked. Added it to the answer.

Comment: @robru It worked!  But now how do I turn it off?  Ack!

Answer (score 9):

My laptop doesn't have a PC speaker, so I needed a software-only solution.  I found an article about setting up GNOME to [play an audio file for the system beep](https://web.archive.org/web/20090906154532/http://tjworld.net/wiki/Linux/Ubuntu/XandGnomeSystemBeepWithAudioFile).

The idea is to set up xkbevd(1) to run a command when a certain event occurs; in this case, the event `Bell`.   For Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty (and possibly previous versions as well), many of the sound files provided are in ogg vorbis format instead of wave, so depending on which sound you want to play on a terminal bell, using aplay(1) may not work.  If you don't already have it, you'll need to install the vorbis-tools package:

```
sudo aptitude install vorbis-tools
```

After that, you'll need to create `~/.xkb/xkbevd.cf` (note the spelling, the article has a typo here) and insert the following:

```
soundDirectory="/usr/share/sounds/"
soundCmd="ogg123 -q"

Bell() "ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg"
```

In order to have the daemon run on login, you can edit your profile as the article suggests, or you can add it to your Startup Applications (System -> Preferences ->Startup Applications).  Click on Add to create a new startup program, set the Name to `XKB Event Daemon`, the command to `xkbevd -bg`, and the comment to `Software terminal bell`.

Comment: use this if you don't want the bell sound to queue: ```Bell() shell "(if [ ! -e /run/lock/bell_playing ]; then touch /run/lock/bell_playing; paplay /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg; rm /run/lock/bell_playing; fi ) &"```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. For me, it was solved by opening "alsamixer" on the console and unmuting the "Beep" slider.

Comment: This worked great for me on Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu 14.04 (and perhaps others), the module-x11-bell module tries to play a bell.ogg sample, which is not loaded in PulseAudio's sample cache. As a workaround to load it manually, type this in a terminal:

```
pactl upload-sample /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg bell.ogg
```

To make this permanent, add the above line inside .xprofile in your home directory (create it if it doesn't exist already).

This command will tell you whether the sample is loaded or not:

```
pactl list samples
```

Answer (score 5):

- Check if pcspkr module is currently loaded

  > $ lsmod | grep pcspkr 
  >   pcspkr          10496  0
- Check if there are any related errors in /var/log/dmesg

  > $ sudo grep pcspkr /var/log/dmesg  
  >   [   15.620198] input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input8

If there's still no clue, do a full manual check of /var/log/dmesg for other errors. A quick grep of the other logs in /var/log/* with today's timestamp might also turn up something.

The above steps are just to help you narrow down the possible issue. With these kind of problems, it can be difficult to guess the answer right off the bat.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to be sure the right module is loaded. If not, the sound control center won't do nothing AFAIK (and even if the module is loaded, I don't know if the bugs mentioned in [this thread](http://www.linux-archive.org/ubuntu-development/265996-2009-i-am-still-hearing-my-pc-speaker.html) are solved in Jaunty).

What version of Ubuntu are you using? Prior to Jaunty, the module was name `snd_pcspkr`.

Can you give us the output of:

```
lsmod | grep pcspkr
```

Can you give us the output of:

```
grep pcspkr /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist*
```

BTW, `pcspkr` is blacklisted by default again in Karmic.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sudo modprobe pcspkr
```

Comment: this works on Dell Latitude 5480 + Ubuntu 16 , together with apt-get installing beep as explained.

Answer (score 2):

http://ubuntu-virginia.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1315929

Post number 6 solved it for me.
In short do the following in a terminal:

1. run 'alsamixer'
2. move to PC Beep
3. press m to unmute
4. set volume
5. press escape

Comment: Thanks - this worked in Ubuntu 12.04.   Critical in my case was the need to unmute the beep in alsamixer.  How do we find out if we have a pc speaker?  (And what was the plan on the developer side anyway in terms of disabling beeping by default?)

Answer (score 2):

I installed [beep](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/beep.1.html) with:

```
sudo aptitude install beep
```

Now I can call beep from shell or script with

```
beep
beep -r 3
```

This program can do much more. See [man beep](http://swoolley.org/man.cgi/beep).

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was a combination of the posts from Leo and nana.galvao:

- run alsamixer, unmute Beep and set a decent volume.
- `sudo modprobe pcspkr`
- and of course install the beep package with `sudo apt-get install beep`

Answer (score 1):

The command `beep` didn't work for me so I came up with an own solution:

```
alias beep="mplayer -ao alsa $HOME/bin/alert.wav &>/dev/null"
```

Where `alert.wav` is a short audio file. Usage:

```
$ sleep 2; beep
```

See my blog post about it [here](https://ubuntuincident.wordpress.com/2013/06/29/beep-when-ready/).

Comment: Doesn't that play it in the speakers and not the buzzer?

Answer (score 0):

I've been researching this problem for a week or so, and I've discovered one of the two machines that I wanted to make beep does not have a built in pc-speaker (weird). So check if there is one.