# GNU/Linux beep from the PC speaker

Tags: linux, audio

How to use (internal) PC speaker instead of external speakers for the "tput bel" sound?
Which parameters should I change?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enable System Beep in Ubuntu](http://superuser.com/questions/22767/enable-system-beep-in-ubuntu)

Comment: @Dennis and the original poster: It may depend on the distro.

Comment: This may also be kernel dependent - I don't have a `pcspkr` module under 2.6.37.1...

Comment: To get the internal speaker to _work_, you need to load the module, but I believe it has been renamed to `snd_spkr` from `pcspkr`. To get the internal speaker to catch the regular PC speaker signal, there might very well be some OS specific setting.

Answer (score 2):

Check your BIOS settings. If the pcspeaker is disabled there, as it is often the case, you won't hear anything no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

Debian has the 'beep' package.  It beeps the speaker, no soundcard needed.

The upstream page is [here](http://johnath.com/beep/)