# Beep works but the bell character makes no sound

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

By loading the `pcspkr` module with `modprobe`, I was able to make the `beep` program work – yes, I'm positive the sound is coming from the on-board beeper and not the sound card.

But

```
echo -e '/a'
```

makes no sound. In my terminal preferences, "audible beep" is selected.

Any clue what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
printf '\a'
```

to print a actual BEL charater.

```
echo -e '/a'
```

prints [SLASH,A] instead of [BEL]

Comment: More generally, note the difference between / and \ -- / is just a regular character to the shell and echo; \ can act as an escape character.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, good point, although `\ ` is also a regular character to `echo`, you need `printf` if you want escape sequences. The single quotes suppress any specialness `/` or `\ ` might have for the shell itself, so its just `printf` or `echo` that matter.

Comment: Still doesn't work, I have tried to write chr(7) to /dev/tty and that doesn't make a sound either.  So I guess the problem is not in the escape sequence...

Comment: @DavidX Hence "can act", not "does act".

Comment: @YanKingYin, huh, I just checked my terminal prefs and I have it enabled as well, and I'm not getting any beeps from `\a` either. (I assumed it was off since I find it rather annoying.) (@MichaelKjörling, fair point.)

Comment: To me, what's annoying is that I couldn't figure out what is causing the bel character not to sound! :(

Answer (score 1):

Okay, per https://superuser.com/a/22769/35630: try editing `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and adding a `#` in front of the `blacklist pcspkr` line. I'm not sure if it works yet since I can't reboot at the moment to test it (for unrelated reasons).