# How to make IRSSI running under screen in a remote system to beep on my local pc for new messages?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, irssi, fedora-16

I have an irssi running forever under a "screen" in a remote linux server system. I have fedora 16 in my laptop and ssh into the server and resume my irssi screen when I come to work.

But I miss a lot of chats as I don't get any notification beeps from irssi. I want my laptop to beep for new messages in my subscribed channels. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/20707/to-make-irssi-system-beep

Comment: @jjlin It's not a duplicate. If I follow the answers in your link, it would beep on the server. I want the beep on my laptop. My question is different.

Comment: Why the heck is it not beeping for you within screen?  Have you disabled the bell in your terminal emulator?  As they say, It works for me(TM).

Comment: @Zoredache Does the remote irssi beep for you in your local machine? What command you used?

Comment: ssh via putty, xterm, or xfce-terminal all seem to work.

Comment: For the note, I wrote a little script that gives notifications bubbles (using libnotify and/or growl) on my github: https://github.com/guyzmo/irssi-over-ssh-notifications because I don't like the beeps, but still need the notifications :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try the steps @jjlin commented above to ensure your pc speaker module is loaded.

Set irssi to beep ON for EVERYTHING to test if it works:

```
/set beep_msg_level ALL
/set bell_beeps ON
```

Tell screen to allow audible beeps with `^a^g`. If you are using a local screen *and* screen on the remote (like I do), you need to tell the remote screen to *also* use audibles. Do this via the screen meta key 'a': `^aa^g`. Toggles these multiple times to switch between visual and audible bells.

`/msg nickserv help` to hear if it works.
Change the bell to clang on highlights only:

```
/set beep_msg_level HILIGHT
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add/edit your $HOME/.screenrc to include:

```
VBELL OFF
```

And/or disable it in a running instance with C-a C-g

The default /etc/screenrc in newer Debian sets VBELL ON for some reason.

Read more at https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Bell

Comment: please add more details to your answer :)